# Why is R's coxph model hazard greater than 1?

Tags: r, cox-model

I take the canned data that is used to demonstrate the coxph function in R, and then I look at the cumulative hazard.

```
require(survival)
options(na.action=na.exclude) # retain NA in predictions
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + ph.ecog + strata(inst), lung)
x <- basehaz(fit)
p <- x[x$strata=='inst=1',]$hazard
plot(p)
```

basehaz is reporting a cumulative hazard function that moves greater than 1.

[image: cumulative hazard plot]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The hazard function needs to be positive but it is not restricted to be smaller than 1.